# How can I make a Pokémon easily level-up?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

While I am playing Pokémon Emerald, I need to defeat some trainers through the game to go to the next badge. I am not into Pokémon, so I don't know exactly if there's an easy way to level-up a Pokémon.

Are there any ideas, tips or tricks (I don't want to use cheats or rare candies)?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use a **rare** candy?  There are a somewhat limited number of them, but there are no downsides. Also, it might help if we knew where you were in the story, or we might end up suggesting leveling tips that you can't access yet.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I don't want to use a rare candy because that candy makes the pokémon sad

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vitamin#Rare_Candy), if anything it [raises their happiness due to level up](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#Generation_III). The only items that lower happiness are [herbal medicines](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Herbal_medicine) (and fainting).

Comment: @TrentHawkins you don't get any EV or IV values when you don't level up through fight. So basically the best thing to do is grinding where you can defeat other Pokémon without the risk of being defeated yourself.

Comment: @GiantTree I'd argue getting 'random' EVs just for the sake of getting EVs isn't all that more helpful (particularly for the story). Like getting +Sp.Atk EVs on a pokemon that won't use them. And you never get IV values; those are static and applied on levelup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to level up is simply to fight Pokémon that you can defeat easily, so it depends entirely on your party composition and where you are in the story. Keep in mind type advantages if you're trying to train a weak Pokémon, or, if it's a very weak Pokémon that won't be able to defeat wild Pokémon at your point in the story, you can follow two methods:

- Send the weak Pokémon out first, then as soon as the fight starts, switch it out for a stronger Pokémon. This causes both Pokémon to gain half of the total experience gained.
- Give the weak Pokémon the Exp. Share you receive in Rustboro City. This will cause the Pokémon to gain half of the total experience points, even if it didn't battle at all.

You can even combine these two, sending out the weak Pokémon first whilst holding the Exp. Share, before switching to a stronger Pokémon. In this case, the weak Pokémon will gain 75% of total experience gained, and the strong Pokémon will gain 25%.

If you can get past your unnatural aversion for Rare Candies, a Pokémon with Pickup will have a chance to find Rare Candies starting from level 21 at 3%, and will have a 10% chance of finding one starting from level 41. It may not sound like a lot, but it adds up if you're fighting many wild Pokémon.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Give them to Pokemon Daycare

On Emerald, it should be located on Route 117, between Verdanturf and Mauvile.

Route 117 should be located on the road highlighted with pink and circled:
[image: Route 117]

Comment: The Day Care is probably the slowest and dullest way of levelling up.

Comment: And you lose good moves and is expensive

Comment: Please post better strategies if you think this is a bad strategy rather than commenting on this. Let the votes decide.

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to raise a real low level pokemon go back to an area and fight enemies closer to its level best if you can find an area that has a weekness to its type of attack...if its ultra low and you have gotten far enough to have gotten an exp share already give it to the guy you want to raise and put him at the back of the roster and fight whatever you can safely...grind through fellow collector....